# Performance issue with scheduleLocalNotification(Large number of local notifications)

Tags: iphone, ios, performance, uilocalnotification, localnotification

I'm facing performance problem with scheduleLocalNotification.
I'm trying to register large number of local notifications. 
It's like birthday alarms for friends. For test, I tried to register about 300 notifications, but my iPhone4 took over 2 minutes. (iPad2 4 seconds, iPhone4S 8 seconds)

Here's a code.

```
-(void)setAllBirthdaysSchedule
{
    Class cls = NSClassFromString(@"UILocalNotification");
    if (cls == nil) {
        return ;
    }

    NSAutoreleasePool *pool = [[NSAutoreleasePool alloc] init];

    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] cancelAllLocalNotifications];

    if (prototypeNotification == nil) {
        prototypeNotification = [[UILocalNotification alloc] init];
        prototypeNotification.repeatCalendar = [NSCalendar currentCalendar];
        prototypeNotification.repeatInterval = NSYearCalendarUnit;

        prototypeNotification.timeZone = [NSTimeZone defaultTimeZone];
        prototypeNotification.fireDate = [NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSinceNow:0];
        prototypeNotification.applicationIconBadgeNumber = 0;
        prototypeNotification.alertBody = NSLocalizedString(@"Body", nil);
        prototypeNotification.alertAction = NSLocalizedString(@"Action", nil);
    }

    NSArray* arr = [self getAllBirthday];

    for (User* user in arr) {                
        UILocalNotification *notif = [prototypeNotification copy];
        notif.fireDate = user.birthday;
        [[UIApplication sharedApplication] scheduleLocalNotification:notif];
        [notif release];

    }

    [pool release];
}
```

Comment: Can a moderator please reopen this? The "duplicate" actually address the local notification limit, while this question addresses the performance issues.

Answer (score 1):

Yes at the older devices it took some time to register a local notification. Try to put the registration into a background thread.

Note that there is a maximum of 64 notifications in iOS, the rest will be discarded. Look at UILocalNotification Class Reference for more information.

Comment: Thanks. I tried it in a background thread, but device is almost freezing even though went to home screen. It's weird.

Comment: @samtaegi Indeed, I witnessed that as well. I was able to fix the issue by processing one notification per runloop. Just create an operation queue, and process one operation at a time asynchronously on the main thread. Assuming the main thread will run 60 times per second, it should distribute the load evenly while still giving the main thread time to work.